# Running a function partly for certain amount of time and save progress

Tags: python, function, time, timing

I made a Python Script that uses basicly 2 functions in a loop.
The first function (clickFast()) needs to be timed nearly perfectly and run as often as possible - it does something very basic and sleeps.
The second function (calculateFully()) is heavily calculating some data for the first function to use.

The second function is only allowed to run while the first function sleeps (so that the first function runs as fast as possible).
Now I want to execute the second function "partly" so I can stop it when the sleep time ends and resume it on the next sleep call.
I attempted to create a third function (calculatePartly(time)) but that is the point I need help with.

I prepared an example script to illustrate that problem:
I want to click onto some position on my screen (the first function).
The position gets "calculated" by the second function (in reality: by making a screenshot and template matchin with a sample.jpg using win32gui and cv2.) Here I used some random values and timer to simulate that behaviour because that code is quite long and uninteresting.

```
import time 
from win32api import SetCursorPos, GetCursorPos, GetAsyncKeyState
import pydirectinput as pd
import random

# That is the data processed by the first function
screenClickPosition = None

# The click delay 
clickDelay = 50 / 1000 # equals 50 miliseconds

# Run this as often as possible
def clickFast():
    # Just do some basic clicking here; no big calculations
    if (screenClickPosition is None):
        return
    
    cursorOriginal = GetCursorPos()
    SetCursorPos(screenClickPosition)

    # Sleep inbetween clicks
    # While I am sleeping I want to calculatePartly() for sleep time and come back here
    #time.sleep(clickDelay)
    calculatePartly(clickDelay)

    pd.keyDown("a")
    pd.keyUp("a")
    
    # While I am sleeping I want to calculatePartly() for sleep time and come back here
    #time.sleep(clickDelay)
    calculatePartly(clickDelay)
    
    SetCursorPos(cursorOriginal)



def calculateFully():
    global screenClickPosition
    screenClickPosition = findClickPositionOnScreen()


# Only calculate screenClickPosition for some specific time
def calculatePartly(timeInMS):
    # ???



def findClickPositionOnScreen():
    # This function takes around 0.3s - 0.6s to return the click position or None if sample.jpg is not found
    # Im using win32gui for the screenshot and cv2 template matching to find a small sample.jpg inside my screen

    # Simulate calculation time
    time.sleep(0.5) 
    
    # Simulating output (either None or some cursor position)
    calculatedPosition = None
    if (bool(random.getrandbits(1))):
        calculatedPosition = GetCursorPos()
    
    return calculatedPosition




def main():
    while True:
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x20)): # Am I pressing spacebar?

            # We can take our time here because there is nothing to click onto yet...
            if (screenClickPosition is None):
                calculateFully() 

            # Call this as often as possible
            clickFast()

        

# Entry
main()
```

The click timing needs to be as precise as possible while the click position can "lag behind".
To be clear: Even when the new click position only gets updated every 5 seconds, I want to click onto that (maybe outdated) position many hundred times, depending on the click delay (which will vary between 0ms and 1second). I want to pause the calculation of the click position to ensure that the timing of my clicks are correct. While the calculation is partly executed, the (old) screenClickPosition needs to stay accessible to click on.

I am currently using Python 3.11.5 64-Bits on Windows 10. I am able to rewrite any code or use any libraries. I need to run it on Windows 10 though.

My implementation idea for the calculatePartly() function:

I check the elapsed time between each command I use to aquire the position (like: 1. take screenshot, 2. find all sample.jpg in screenshot, 3. calculate nearest found sample.jpg to the mouse position. All those steps can be broken down to even more commands). If enough time elapses, I save my progress. On the next call of calculatePartly() I first check the previously saved progress to know where to start

```
calculatePartlyStoppedId = 0
calculatePartlyData = None

# Only calculate screenClickPosition for some specific time
def calculatePartly(timeInMS):
    global calculatePartlyStoppedId
    global calculatePartlyData
    start = time.time() # get current timestamp

    if (calculatePartlyStoppedId == 1):
        # start with cmd2
        # ...
        # repeat 1000 lines of code here...
        # ...
        pass
    elif (calculatePartlyStoppedId == 2):
        # start with cmd3
        # ...
        # repeat 999 lines of code here...
        # ...
        pass
    #elif... for every ID
    
    # cmd1
    time.sleep(0.01)

    # Check if enough time is passed
    if (time.time() - start >= timeInMS):
        calculatePartlyStoppedId = 1
        calculatePartlyData = [] # put all the values aquired up to this point into here
        return
    
    # cmd2
    time.sleep(0.01)

    # Check if enough time is passed
    if (time.time() - start >= timeInMS):
        calculatePartlyStoppedId = 2
        calculatePartlyData = [] # put all the values aquired up to this point into here
        return
    
    # repeat for every command
    # ...
```

This is a terrible idea because if I need to change 1 line of code (in my calculations) I would need to change 100s lines (and I would repeat the code multiple hundred times).
Idealy I only have one calculate()-function with some sort of "debug-breakpoints" which remember where the function stopped last.